# Want to remove specific records using sed

Tags: sed

i am trying to delete some records from input file.

```
list.txt
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,8,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,8,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
```

Expected output:
list.txt

```
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1 -> deleted records above this and matching [tag1,slate1,flag1]
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
```

I tried using code:

```
sed '/tag2,slate2,flag2,status0/d' list1.txt
```

But this delete records tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1, tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2, etc.. also.

is there any way to stop sed when record reached 'tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1 ?

and 'tag1,slate1,flag1,status0' not found then no need to remove any records matching 'tag1,slate1,flag1'

Any suggestions to get output.

Comment: What is the rule for `above this -> tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1 ` ? the whole line?

Comment: And would `awk` be okay, too?

Comment: awk also okay for this

Comment: all record matching 'tag1,slate1,flag1' need to delete till we got last matching record 'tag1,slate1,flag1,status0' we need to stop deleting records matching 'tag1,slate1,flag1'

Comment: aah, the last matching pattern should stay, okay. Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```bsh
awk '
NR == FNR && /tag1,slate1,flag1,status0/{last_matching=FNR}
NR != FNR && FNR<last_matching && /tag1,slate1,flag1/{next}
NR != FNR
' list.txt list.txt
```

`awk` reads the file twice.

- On the first run (`NR == FNR`) ...

  - we save the last matching `FNR` (= record/line number of the file) in a variable.
- On the second run (`NR != FNR`) ...

  - we will skip all matching lines (--> `/tag1,slate1,flag1/{next}`)
  - but only until `last_matching`(--> `FNR<last_matching`).
  - and print all remaining lines with `NR != FNR`.

Comment: Thank you working fine.

Comment: one more thing if 'tag1,slate1,flag1,status0'  not found then no need to remove any records matching 'tag1,slate1,flag1' , Can you adjust code in this way please?

Answer (score 0):

Using **sed** stream editor utility we can do as follows:

```
sed -ne ':top
/^tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1$/!{
  /^tag1,slate1,flag1,/!p;n
  btop
}
:n;p;n;bn
' list.txt
```

- Until we see the target line we keep printing non matching lines.
- As soon as the target line is met, we keep printing all lines until the file is exhausted.